# Gradle Resolve Duplicate Hardcoded Classes

Tags: gradle

I got duplicate classes error in gradle, and I know the cause.

It is because there are library X and library Y both have a dependency to package "com.some.package", but instead of specifying it as their dependency, they manually included it into their jar.

So the libraryX.jar contains these packages:

```
com.X
and
com.some.package
```

while libraryY.jar contains these packages:

```
com.Y
and
com.some.package
```

Therefore, the following solution wouldn't work:

```
implementation(X){
    exclude(group = "com.some.package")
}
```

since it is not a transitive dependency.

I can surely repackage one of those libraries manually and discard the duplicate package, but I don't like the idea of doing that every time I upgrade the dependency. Is there any clean way to resolve this?

Thanks.